# How to randomise and mimic a rollover in jquery?

Tags: jquery, random, effects, rollover

I have a JQuery script which acts as a simple image rollover with a nice fade effect.

Here is a test version of the current script in action - http://fi-testing.co.uk/SO/rubix-cube.html

As you can see, there are 9 blocks, the client wishes for the rollovers to occur randomly (without a hover) to kind of create a ripple/pulsating effect.

How would this be achieved with either JQuery or php?, and would It be possible that hovering over breaks the randomisation and acts as normal?

Sorry if any of this is unclear.

Thanks for any help.

Dan

Comment: I assume you know the difference between server-side languages like PHP and client-side languages like JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going too much into your code, you can create randomness by `Math.random()`

so if you have an array of your cube entires, indexed 0 - 8, you may use

```
var randomNumber = parseInt( Math.random() * 9 );
var randomCube = cubes[randomNumber];
```

you can use `setInterval` to get this to repeat once in every *x* ms

```
function randomlyChangeCubes() { ... }

...

setInterval( randomlyChangeCubes, 2000 );
```

you can use jQuery `trigger` to invoke the `hover` effect manually, but I'd say it'd be more readable to extract the code you have in `hover` to a function which you call both from `hover` and from `randomlyChangeCubes`.

All that being said... doing this entirely randomly probably won't make it look rippling/pulsating...

Answer (score 0):

Things you would need:

setTimeout/setInterval = call you 'effect' function at a set time
random number = use this to call the required element randomly eg #box1, #box2 etc.

I think thats it - should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to accomplish a cool looking randomness. The `Math.random()` method produces pseudo-random values from the uniform distribution (i.e., all values in the range have the same probability) and that will not look nice.

I'm not an expect and I cannot tell you what distribution will yield better results but you can try the normal and poisson distributions:

http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/JAVASCRP/BINOMPOI.HTM (see page source for code)